# [Help]Extract from csv file and output txt(python)[Help]

Tags: python, csv, txt

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dj6uG.jpg)

I read the file 'average-latitude-longitude-countries.csv' to the Southern Hemisphere.

Print the country name of the country in the file 'result.txt'

Question:

I want you to fix it so that it can be printed according to the image file.

```
infile = open("average-latitude-longitude-countries.csv","r")
outfile = open("average-latitude-longitude-countries.txt","w")
joined = []
infile.readline()
for line in infile:
  splited = line.split(",")
  if len(splited) > 4:
    if float(splited[3]) < 0:
      joined.append(splited[2])
      outfile.write(str(joined) + "\n")
  else:
    if float(splited[2]) < 0:
      joined.append(splited[1])
      outfile.write(str(joined) + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard without posting a head/first few lines of the CSV
However, assuming your code works and the countries list is successfully populated.
Then,
you can replace the line

```
outfile.write(str(joined) + '\n')
```

**with:**

```
outfile.write("\n".join(joined))
```

***OR***

with those 2 lines:

```
for country in joined:
    outfile.write("%s\n" % country)
```

Keep in mind, those approaches just do the job. however, not optimum

*Extra hints:*

you can have a look at [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module of standard Python. can make your parsing easier

Also, `splited = line.split(",")` can lead to wrong output , if there a single quoted field that contains "," .
like this : field1_value,"**field 2,value**",field3, field4 , ...

**Update:**
Now I got you, First of all you are dumping the whole aggregated array to the file for each line you read.
you should keep adding to the array in the loop. then after the whole loop, dump in once (Splitting the accumulated array like above)

Here is your code slightly modified:

```
infile = open("average-latitude-longitude-countries.csv","r")
outfile = open("average-latitude-longitude-countries.txt","w")
joined = []
infile.readline()
for line in infile:
  splited = line.split(",")
  if len(splited) > 4:
    if float(splited[3]) < 0:
      joined.append(splited[2])
      #outfile.write(str(joined) + "\n")

  else:
    if float(splited[2]) < 0:
      joined.append(splited[1])
      #outfile.write(str(joined) + '\n')


outfile.write("\n".join(joined))
```

Comment: Could you attach the code so that it can be printed according to the image file?

Comment: I'm sorry, but there's nothing on the txt file. Please check.

Comment: The program should work, provided same input as provided by the image . Try putting break points in an IDE. Step through the lines of execution .  This should give you a clue